# Swift - Passing value back to ViewController using protocol and delegate

Tags: ios, swift, protocols

I'm new to swift and my problem right now is I want to pass the value from RoutePreviewController page back to display on ViewController page after clicking on the Navigate Button. As below picture, you can see that the RoutePreviewController is not directly segue from the ViewController.

[This is my story board of the swift project on xcode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pWjmy.png)

However, I tried using protocol and delegate in the code.

Here are codes that I have add to the ViewController (MainPage)

```
protocol HandleSelectedPath{
    func selectedPathDraw(selectedRoute:[(line:Int?,node:Int,time:Double)])
}
```

in viewDidLoad of ViewController

```
    let routePreviewPage = storyboard!.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("RoutePreviewController") as! RoutePreviewController
    routePreviewPage.handleSelectedPathDelegate = self
```

and an extension outside the ViewController class

```
extension ViewController : HandleSelectedPath{
    func selectedPathDraw(selectedRoute:[(line:Int?,node:Int,time:Double)]){
        print("7687980")
        selectedPath = selectedRoute
        routeDraw()
    }
}
```

And in RoutePreviewController, I have delegation of the protocol.

```
var handleSelectedPathDelegate: HandleSelectedPath? = nil
```

and the Navigate button action

```
@IBAction func navigateButtonAction(sender: AnyObject) {
    handleSelectedPathDelegate?.selectedPathDraw(previewPath)
    dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
    definesPresentationContext = true
}
```

As a result, after clicking the Navigate button, it does send me back to the ViewController page but the selectedPathDraw function of the protocol is not performed. I also tried printing some random string but nothing came up as an output.

Answer (score 0):

The reference for your `RoutePreviewController` according to your code above only exist inside your `viewDidLoad`, you have to set as property instead like this:

```
var routePreviewPage: RoutePreviewController!
```

Always it's a good practice implement your `delegate` as a weak reference to avoid retain-cycles, so the correct way of implement your delegate and protocol should be as the following code:

```
protocol HandleSelectedPath: class {
   func selectedPathDraw(selectedRoute:[(line:Int?,node:Int,time:Double)])
}
```

> **RoutePreviewController**:

```
weak var handleSelectedPathDelegate: HandleSelectedPath?

@IBAction func navigateButtonAction(sender: AnyObject) {
   handleSelectedPathDelegate?.selectedPathDraw(previewPath)
   dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
   definesPresentationContext = true
}
```

> **`viewDidLoad` of ViewController**:

```
routePreviewPage = storyboard!.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("RoutePreviewController") as! RoutePreviewController
routePreviewPage.handleSelectedPathDelegate = self
```

I hope this help you.

Comment: I got one on the bitbucket. Here is the download link https://bitbucket.org/bhbo/smartcommuter/downloads

Comment: I just downloaded your code but it's a little big and I don't have any idea in how reach the `RoutePreviewController`

Comment: If you open the project on Xcode you have to find the 'Controller' folder, both ViewController and RoutePreviewController store in the folder.